# Logic to create a multilingual site

Tags: php, translation, fuelphp

I have a site and am done, but future multilanguage support is not implemented,

I'm using the fuelphp framework for generating my website. I already checked out this documentation http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/lang.html for language config in fuelphp, 
but I'm still confused how to implement that function.

My questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to create multilanguage in fuelphp?
2. Can you suggest to me logic to creating multilanguage in site?

Comment: Thank you for fixing the grammar RegDwight. That was hard to bear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not that experienced with fuelphp, but the documentation tells you everything you need to know.

You need to create PHP files, which contain all the different translations as an array, sorted by language codes as in:

en.php

```
return array(
    "Text_Hello" => "Hello",
    "Text_Bye" => "Good bye"
);
```

de.php

```
return array(
    "Text_Hello" => "Hallo",
    "Text_Bye" => "Auf Wiedersehen"
);
```

Next, you need to implement a session management, which stores the current language information of the user you're currently dealing with, as in:

```
session_start();
Lang::load($_SESSION['lang']);
```

And each time, you need to output something, you need to call the 'get'-function.

```
echo Lang::get("Text_Hello");
```

Just as an example.

Though, if I may suggest an alternative, there's a gettext library usually built into PHP.
The function call is simply _("Text_Hello"); after setting the locale according to the session data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about fuelphp, but the way you handle multiple languages in PHP is with: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Comment: Haha, I suggested the same thing at the end of my post :D

Answer (score 2):

the documentation link you provided describes it self and clearly, you will have to create saperate language files at the locations as fuelphp demands wich contains

```
return array(
    'hello' => 'Hello :name',
    'something'=> 'something :name!',
    'test'=> array('hello' => 'Hello', 'something' => 'Plop') // Group
);
```

at any request comnes

```
Config::set('language', 'THE_LANGUAGE_IDENTIFIERR_YOU_RECIEVE_OR STORE_IN_SESSION');
```

further than you have to use function calls of lang class like

Lang::get('hello', array('name' => 'world')); // will return hello world

and if you want to use google translator for free check this out http://rupeshpatel.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/usage-of-google-translator-api-for-free/